# Heroku Deployment App Crashing with Error Code H10

Tags: heroku

I am facing an issue while deploying reactioncommerce to heroku. On checking the error log the error code is H10. The error log shows

```
 npm ERR! missing script: start.
```

I don't have any clue to resolve the issue. Can anybody point me into the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be in your `package.json` under the scripts category. See this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script

You should also create a `Procfile` which is described in a link from the above linked article.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already too late to answer, but for some other who may end up being here. The error message state clearly that the start script is missing. You can simply add start script to your package.json file. `"start": "node app.js"`